# Halt/stop GWT from executing

Tags: java, gwt

In our GWT web application, we reach a state where we want to remove everything and just show a big fat warning that the application was stopped.

We are not able to figure out a way to do that. What we basically need is:

- force GWT to stop all processing and abort any existing RPC messages
- force all registered events to become inactive
- clear all visible content from the page
- set a single paragraph/text

In a nutshell, we want to kill the entire DOM and add just a single paragraph to it.

We tried many different combinations of

```
RootPanel.get().clear()
```

but found no reliable way to do what we want to achieve. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: RootPanel.get().clear();RootPanel.get().add(warningMessageWidget); while(true);

Comment: `while(true)` will lock up the entire browser thread, until the browser decides to shut down your app. In some browsers, this will stop all tabs, not just the one your app is running in.

Comment: Reload the page with the new content?

Comment: RootPanel.get().getElement().setInnerHTML("");?

Comment: I tried all the combinations of RootPanel.get(). ... setInnerHtml, clear, whatever. They all don't work. It seems event processing continues adding stuff to the page.

Comment: The problem is that there is no such System.exit(0) in a browser - it is up to the user when they want to leave the page. Often you can't even close the browser window from under them. Consider just navigating to a new page - that will completely unload the page. But remember, the user controls the browser, and can always navigate back. Anything past this, and you really need to have specific application logic to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to take of server activities. That's a good practice, which makes your application robust.
To make it uniform, you probably want to respond with appropriate exception to any requests made to your Service implementations. For instance, if that's what happens when user is removed rights to access the application, then it should probably throw some kind of security exception for all requests except those made for relogin or other approved actions.

You can do it manually in every service method or you can have a filter that handles that. Frameworks such as Spring Security provide an easy way to configure security filters.

After you've done with server side and confirmed that UI is unable to penetrate through server's security layer, you can make changes to UI. There are different ways to make a nice looking blocking screen.

In general, I do the following in my code to create content and can use clear() method to remove viewport or stuff from the viewport. No refresh or revalidation needed.

```
    Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
    viewport.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    viewport.add(new MainPanel());
    RootPanel.get().add(viewport);
```

Not sure how your layout is. If you're able to provide a code sample for your scenario, I can show you how to do what you need. Because in my examples it works just fine.

Comment: I think the main problem I'm having is that I need to stop event processing so that after clearing everything no new stuff gets added...

Comment: Stopping event processing is never an elegant solution. What you should do instead is to ignore events in this state of your application. Alternatively, you can disconnect your data model from whatever is feeding it with new events/data.

Answer (score 1):

```
Window.Location.replace("URL-OF-A-STATIC-HTML")
```

Javadoc :

> Replaces the current URL with a new one. All GWT state will be lost.
>   In the browser's history, the current URL will be replaced by the new
>   URL.

If you want to re-activate the GWT app, put a link on that HTML page.

Comment: That's exactly the way I have done it currently. I forward to some kind of error page. However, this is only possible if I still have a server connection. If server is down and my GWT app notices that and wants to inform the user about it, there is no chance to forward user to a static page, which must be retrieved from the server.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean... the URL-OF-A-STATIC-HTML might not be reachable anymore ? Maybe you can cache it offline at startup, using HTML5 and a manifest file if your client's browser supports it;

Answer (score 0):

Store information or say flag in the cookies, when ever u load the application see that whether that cookie is set, if it is set display the message or else load the application. Now whenever you want to stop the application completely, set the cookie and reload the application.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my question. I'm not asking how to know that my app should stop. I'm just looking for a GWT way to say `exit(0);`...